# Remote Events Forwarding

Tags: powershell, event-handling, powershell-remoting, custom-events

I am using PowerShell Remoting using PSSession to perform a job on my remote machine. I need to be notified periodically about the remote job. I am using the `Register-EngineEvent` and `New-Event` cmdlets to achieve this.

- Remote session creation:

  ```
  $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName server1
  ```
- Registering the engine event with action block to automatically handle the forwarded remote events with source id 'MyEvent'

  ```
  Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyEvent -Action {
      Write-Host ("Got message from server1:"-f $event.messagedata)
  }
  ```

Consider this sample remote job that will raise a custom event using the `New-Event` cmdlet with the same sourceid 10 times with some time interval (2 secs).

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyEvent -Forward
    $count = 1
    while ($count -le 10) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier MyEvent -Message 'Hai' | Out-Null
        $count++
    }
}
```

My problem is the eventjob (i.e. the action block) is getting executed only after the remote job is finished. I need the action block in local session to be executed every 2 seconds but the actions for all the 10 events are getting executed only after the remote job is finished and so I am missing the live updates from the remote job.

Is there anything I can do to meet my expectation?

Comment: Try invoking the remote command as a background job (`-AsJob`).

Comment: Yes, it's working... thank you @Ansgar Wiechers